# Can't send mail with MH-E (nmh)

Tags: email, emacs, smtp

I can't seem to get MH-E configured correctly for sending mail. I have no problem in receiving and perusing mail.

- ~/.authinfo has correct credentials for SMTP server
- ~/.netrc has correct credentials for SMTP server
- My .mh_profile:

  MH-Profile-Version: 1.0
  Path: /home/mydir/Mail
  Editor: emacsclient
  credentials: file:netrc
  post: -mts smtp -server smtp.1and1.com -port -user "myusername" -tls -port 587
- In my .emacs:

  (setq mail-user-agent 'mh-e-user-agent)
  (setq message-mail-user-agent t)

After I compose my message and hit C-c C-c to send I get this response:

```
post: problem initializing server; [RPLY] 530 Authentication required
send: message not delivered to anyone
```

I assume it's not getting the password. I see no method for providing that to MH-E or nmh directly, it seems it's supposed to come from .netrc or .authinfo.

I'm hoping someone can help. I've been Googling for days and the documentation is not very clear on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

Per man post on my system:

> post does not consult the user's .mh_profile

Instead, it is documented to consult mts.conf, globally, and (I assume) ~/.mts.conf -- hope this helps.